# How to get JSON with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am trying to get my table filled with data. The url gives json back, but I don't know how to call json in angular.

This my my services.js:

```
angular.module('OrganisatieApp.services', [])
.factory('organisatieAPIservice', function($resource) {

    var organisatieAPIservice = [];
organisatieAPIservice.getOrganisaties = function(){
    return $http({
        method: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
        url: 'http://jbossews-themaopdracht78.rhcloud.com/rest/json/org/Organisaties'
    });

}
        return organisatieAPIservice;
        })
```

controller.js :

```
      angular.module('OrganisatieApp.controllers', []).
    controller('organisatieController',function($scope, organisatieAPIservice) {

        $scope.organisatieList = [];

            organisatieAPIservice.getOrganisaties().success(function (response) {
                //Assign response in Callback
                $scope.organisatieList = response();
            });
});
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('OrganisatieApp', [
    'OrganisatieApp.controllers',
    'OrganisatieApp.services' ]);
```

My html div :

```
    <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Organisatie naam</th>
                        <th>Organisatie plaats</th>
                        <th>Organisatie Curriculum</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="organisatie in organisatieList">
                        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="/img/logos/{{organisatie.Organisatie.logo}}.png" />
                            {{organisatie.Organisatie.orgNaam}}&nbsp;{{organisatie.Organisatie.orgVolledig}}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{organisatie.Constructors[0].provincie}}</td>
                        <td>{{organisatie.curriculum}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Opleidingsprofiel</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Aantal Organisaties<span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </h3>
            </div>



            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Organisatie naam</th>
                        <th>Organisatie plaats</th>
                        <th>Organisatie Curriculum</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="organisatie in organisatieList">
                        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="/img/logos/{{organisatie.Organisatie.logo}}.png" />
                            {{organisatie.Organisatie.orgNaam}}&nbsp;{{organisatie.Organisatie.orgVolledig}}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{organisatie.Constructors[0].provincie}}</td>
                        <td>{{organisatie.curriculum}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know that i am trying to call jsonp but how do I call for json.

Comment: Change $scope.organisatieList = response() to response. Make sure that organisatie.Organisatie.orgNaam is there in the response.

Comment: use console to check for errors. Since `$http` was never injected as dependency should throw error when you try to use it ... big clue to troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are couple of problem with your code.

1. Your `jsonp` call url must have `callback` parameter with value `JSON_CALLBACK` like `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` & its should be of type `jsonp`.

**Code**

```
return $http.jsonp({'http://jbossews-themaopdracht78.rhcloud.com/rest/json/org/Organisaties?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'});
```

**OR**

```
return $http({
    method: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://jbossews-themaopdracht78.rhcloud.com/rest/json/org/Organisaties?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
});
```

2. You should do change `$scope.organisatieList = response();` to `$scope.organisatieList = response;` because the response contains a data.

   ```
   organisatieAPIservice.getOrganisaties().success(function (response) {
       //Assign response in Callback
       $scope.organisatieList = response;
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In this line, just add the "$http" as a dependency of your service, like this:

```
angular.module('OrganisatieApp.services', [])
.factory('organisatieAPIservice', function($resource,$http) {
    //your code here
```

You need to add this to be able to send the request, otherwise for angular the $http variable is not defined (or imported as a dependency). And yes, like @pankajparkar and @vishnu say, you need to change in your controller this line:

```
$scope.organisatieList = response();
```

For this one:

```
$scope.organisatieList = response;
```